# Connected components of a coset space

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, quotient-spaces, quotient-group, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H\leq G$ be a subgroup.

Let $p\;\colon G\to\pi_0\left(G\right)$ be the quotient map, $G_0$ be the identity path component of $G$ and $\left(G/H\right)_0$ be the path component of $G/H$ containing the coset $H$. Then I think these are true, but I can't seem to prove them:
$$
\pi_0\left(G/H\right)\cong\pi_0\left(G\right)/p\left(H\right)\\
\left(G/H\right)_0\cong G_0/\left(G_0\cap H\right)$$

Comment: I assume that by $\pi_0(G)$ you mean $G/G_0$?

Comment: Is $G_0$ is the component of the identity or its path component?

Comment: I meant the path component

Comment: @freakish Yes. That's what I mean, where $G_0$ is the path component of $G$ containing identity